# SYSTEM ERROR: I/O error 0 in writeto, ret 2048, file 56(/mfgtmp/tmp/srtE5yybD), addr 77010944. (290) - PROGRESS 4GL

Tags: linux, openedge, progress-4gl

I am getting below error suddenly when my progress program was executed and running for more than 80 minutes. I think this is OS error and error 0 says its for out of disk space. I checked the disk space as it shows 14 GB available but I am not sure why I am getting this error.

Is it because of on a write out of disk space(exceeding 14 GB) and stopped ? so that available 14 GB kept same as it is?

**SYSTEM ERROR: I/O error 0 in writeto, ret 2048, file 56(/mfgtmp/tmp/srtE5yybD), addr 77010944. (290)**

Answer (score 3):

By default temp files are created "unlinked". Because of this the space they were using is automatically reclaimed by the OS if the session crashes so you will often have a situation where your temp file ran out of space, the session crashed, and then when you investigate there is plenty of free space.

You can change the default behavior by using the -t (lower case) startup parameter. This will result in the files not being removed if a session crashes - so the space will not be returned to the OS. You will have to manually delete "stale" files if you enable -t.

On UNIX -t will also make the files visible in the -T (upper case) directory so that you can see their growth in real time.

On Windows the files are always visible and the current length is not consistently reported by system tools.

If your temp files are being written to a different filesystem than your working directory (the -T startup parameter is where temp files go) then you should have a "protrace.pid" file corresponding to the crashed session's process id and the timestamp of the crash. This will then lead you to the 4gl code that was creating the very large srt file.

14GB is far beyond "reasonable" so you really should look at that code and see if there is a better way to do whatever it is doing.

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of k-base articles on that issue, for instance: https://knowledgebase.progress.com/articles/Knowledge/000027351

When you check disk space, please make sure you're checking the correct file system (/mfgtmp in this case).

The error messages references an srt file - so you might want to try to use srt file less heavy, see this article for some initial help: https://knowledgebase.progress.com/articles/Knowledge/P95930

Or: https://knowledgebase.progress.com/articles/Knowledge/P84475

Comment: Is it possible to change the path mfgtmp through program? so that I can avoid this out of disk space and export to the path where it has huge space

Comment: Is this the path where we getting out of disk space ? (/mfgtmp/tmp/srtE5yybD)

Comment: as Tom noted 14GB is beyond reasonable. fixing the code will be way better than throwing more disk space at it. Once the code is fixed I guess it will run a lot faster as well